# R cannot find shell.exec (Mac OSX)

Tags: r, macos, shell, unix

I'm new to R and RStudio; using them in Mac OSX 10.15.7. I'm trying to run a user-written program to perform some stats and output results to a pre-organized excel spreadsheet that visualizes them in a specific way.

The program does not work on my machine, but apparently works on the program author's machine (I spoke to them).

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
[1/2] Analysing proc traj outcomes
[2/2] Writing output file
Error in shell.exec(output_file) : could not find function "shell.exec"
```

I searched the syntax for mentions of shell.exec and found the following:

```
 step <- step + 1
        cat(paste0("[", step, "/", total, "] Writing output file\n"))
        if (xlsx_output){
                create_excel(bic_df, prob_df)
                if (open_file){
                        shell.exec(file.path(output_file))
                }
        } else{
                create_txt(bic_df, prob_df)
                if (open_file){
                        shell.exec(output_file)
                        shell.exec(output_txt)
                }
        }
```

I apologize for the newbie-ness of the question. Any advice welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell.exec` is a Windows-only command in R. The closest thing to `shell.exec(x)` on MacOS is `system2("open", x)`.  However, what happens when you run it may be different, since it depends on file associations on the system, so it's not guaranteed to be an exact equivalent.